# create data frame containing rows that add up to 100

Tags: r

This is my first stab at this:

```
library(dplyr)

step_size <- 5

grid <- expand.grid(
    x1 = seq(0, 100, step_size)
    , x2 = seq(0, 100, step_size)
    , x3 = seq(0, 100, step_size)
)

grid$sum = grid$x1 + grid$x2 + grid$x3
grid$x1 <- (grid$x1 / grid$sum) * 100
grid$x2 <- (grid$x2 / grid$sum) * 100
grid$x3 <- (grid$x3 / grid$sum) * 100
grid$sum <- grid$x1 + grid$x2 + grid$x3

nrow(grid)

result <- distinct(grid) %>% filter(!is.na(sum))

head(result, 20)
nrow(result)
```

Basically, I want to create a data frame that contains as many rows as possible that add up to 100 and are uniformly distributed.

is there an easier better approach in R? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `data.table`...

```
library(data.table)

grid <- expand.grid(
  x1 = seq(0, 100)
  , x2 = seq(0, 100)
  , x3 = seq(0, 100)
)

setDT(grid)

res <- grid[grid[, rowSums(.SD) == 100], ]
res[, summation := rowSums(.SD)]
```

Result:

```
> res[, unique(summation)]
[1] 100
```

This can also be done in `base` but `data.table` is faster:

```
library(data.table)

grid <- expand.grid(
  x1 = seq(0, 100)
  , x2 = seq(0, 100)
  , x3 = seq(0, 100)
)


grid2 <- expand.grid(
  x1 = seq(0, 100)
  , x2 = seq(0, 100)
  , x3 = seq(0, 100)
)

setDT(grid)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  data.table = {        
    res <- grid[grid[, rowSums(.SD) == 100], ]
  },
  base = {
    res2 <- grid2[rowSums(grid2) == 100, ]
  }
)

Unit: milliseconds
       expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
 data.table 59.41157  89.6700 109.0462 107.7415 124.2675 183.9730   100  a 
       base 65.70521 109.6471 154.1312 125.4238 156.9168 611.0169   100   b
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple function. You can specify how many rows/columns you want, and what each row sums to.

```
func <- function(cols = 3, rows = 10, rowTotal = 100) {
  dt1 <- replicate(n = cols, runif(n = rows))
  dt1 <- data.frame(apply(X = dt1, MARGIN = 2, FUN = function(x) x / rowSums(dt1) * rowTotal))
  return(dt1)
}

rowSums(func()) # default values (3 cols, 10 rows, each row sums to 100) 
rowSums(func(cols = 5, rows = 10, rowTotal = 50)) # 5 cols, 10 rows, row sums to 50)
```

Comment: Not sure if it's possible to generate variables that are uniformly distributed though. You might also want to check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11003967/generate-3-random-number-that-sum-to-1-in-r